# How to modify Random().Next() to Autoincrementing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am doing an ASP.NetCore MVC Project.

Following is the code I am using to insert the primary key of the table `'ImageFile'`.
(It has attributes like: `Id`, `UserID`, `ImageName`, `Size`, `URl` etc. UserId is a foreign key).

```
ImageFile imageFile = new ImageFile();
imageFile.Id = new Random().Next();
```

This just inserts a random number into the `Id` field of the table.
Ex:

| ID | UserId | ImageName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1513570791 | 2 | image1.png |
| 1714580687 | 2 | image2.png |
| 5909420604 | 2 | image3.png |

How can I modify the above code snippet to insert an auto-incrementing value to the table ?
Ex:

| ID | UserId | ImageName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | image1.png |
| 2 | 2 | image2.png |
| 3 | 2 | image3.png |

Thank you.

Comment: How did you define the table? There are "autonumber" options available to have the table generate a (sequential) ID

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I am used database first approach to implement the model classes. So, annotations are there in Model class

Comment: @Arcturus I am using a microsoft sql database

Comment: A kind request. can somebody tell me how to make tables in stackoverflow, please. In preview it works fine. but when posting it get jammed

Comment: @AbdulAsim you're right about the tables in preview; I'm going to feed that back to our dev folks who work in markdown

Comment: A tip: Don't create `new Random()` per value. Create it once e.g. in private field and call that field `rndGen.Next()` to get the random number.

Comment: @AbdulAsim use [markdown table](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables) syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From comments

> "I am using a microsoft sql database"

Then: define the column (presumably `Id`) as `IDENTITY(1,1)`, for example `Id int not null IDENTITY(1,1)` - and you're done. Now the database assigns the value during `INSERT` - starting from 1 and incrementing 1 each time, and you cannot `UPDATE` it etc. If you are using an ORM such as EF, you will need to tell it that the column is database owned; there's usually an attribute for that (so it doesn't try to push that value into the database), for example `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`.